# Haskell idiom for 'selective' map

Tags: haskell, dictionary

Suppose one wants to `map` over a collection, but only collect results of the mapped function if the mapped-upon value meets certain criteria. I am currently doing this as such:

```
func = foldl (\acc x, ->  (maybeGrab x):acc) []


maybeGrab a
    | a > 5 = [someFunc a]
    | otherwise = []
```

While this works, I am sure there is a more idiomatic 'right/common/more recognisable' way to do this.

Comment: Does filter not do what you need?  Or perhaps mapMaybe from Data.Maybe?

Comment: @JeffFoster: `mapMaybe` is the correct answer. You should post it as an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: Yes, Jeff is right. The forthcoming answer has my vote.

Comment: BTW, you could also have used concatMap instead of that funky fold (particularly useful in the cases where maybeGrab can yield multiple results in case of success)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

mapMaybe from the Data.Maybe package looks like it does the job.  The documentation says:

> The mapMaybe function is a version of map which can throw out elements. In particular, the functional argument returns something of type Maybe b. If this is Nothing, no element is added on to the result list. If it just Just b, then b is included in the result list.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would do this in two stages: first, eliminate the values you don't care about, then map.

```
func = map someFunc . filter (>5)
```

This can also be expressed nicely as a list comprehension.

```
func xs = [someFunc x | x <- xs, x > 5]
```

Comment: If the desired filter depends on the *produced value*, you can, of course, reverse the order: `filter cond . map someFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This definitely seems like a place where a fold is just fine. What about:

```
func = foldl (\acc x -> let a = g x in if a > 5 then a:acc else acc) []
```

Here `g` is the function you are trying to map over the list.

I can't think of any function that natively combines map and filter without folding.

[EDIT]

Oh, apparently there is a mapMaybe. Never used that before. I stand corrected. Ha, learn something all the time.

Comment: Eek `foldl`! You just lost your ability to stream this list.

Comment: Well, there isn't one that's *better* between foldl' and foldr. If he was processing a large list, non-infinite, he would reduce space overhead with a foldl'. If, however, you mentioned he was streaming or working with an infinite list, foldr would be the only way he could do it.

Comment: Nope.  Space overhead in `foldl'` is Theta(output list).  Spaceoverhead for `foldr` is O(output list).  `foldl'` does the whole computation before returning, `foldr` inherits the computational structure of its user.  `foldl'` is a loser when the output type is not flat, as in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting these big o's/theta. Foldl' will sum, for instance, over a list of integers in constant space. Foldr will build out a larger thunk depending on the size of the list. I think we are both right, it's just a matter of whether or not the fold function is lazy in the first, second or both of its arguments and whether or the whnf of the first argument is reduced.

Comment: Either way, I think we are beyond the scope of the OP's question and should find venue elsewhere to continue this convo.